# Cannot set env with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I use `create-react-app` with `react-script` version `1.0.7`, `node 6.10.2`

In my project root, I create `.env`:

```
API_ENDPOINT=https://dev-api.com
```

And in `src/common/api.js`, I have:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const apiEndpoint = process.env.API_ENDPOINT;
axios.defaults.baseURL = apiEndpoint || 'https://prod-api.com';
```

After building the project with `yarn run build`, I check the api call from browser console and it always is `https://prod-api.com`.

Do you have any ideas. Thanks

Comment: Are there any other .env files in your project root? .env is the last prioritized env file for react-scripts.

Comment: @AaronF no there isnt. I also tried other `.env.*` files but it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read the [docs](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables) again. 
Environment variable should start with `REACT_APP_`:

> By default you will have NODE_ENV defined for you, and any other
>   environment variables starting with REACT_APP_